# does installing a new version of cuda in a python virtual environment have an effect on the whole system?

Tags: python, cuda, virtualenv

I have cuda 9.2 already installed on my system and I want to install cuda 8.0 in a python virtual environment. I don't want the installation of cuda 8.0 to take effect on the whole system, because I don't want the cuda drivers to change and I don't want to have specify which cuda I want to use each time. For these reasons, before I attempt to install a new version on a virtual environment, could you please tell me if it will install it on the whole system? (as if I hadn't used a virtual environment)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can have multiple CUDA versions installed without any problem. When creating a virtual environment, you can specify which CUDA version you want it to use. Make certain not to select the driver for installation when you install CUDA 8 and everything should work.

Comment: OK but I can do his without the use of a virtual environment. What I want to know is: in this case, does it make a difference to use a virtual environment, will the virtual environment isolate cuda 8.0?

Comment: A Python virtual environment has absolutely nothing to do with CUDA. They are orthogonal. There is no such thing as "installing! CUDA within a Python virtual environment. The closest thing is in Anaconda, and there it isn't actually a CUDA installation, just a Conda specific copy of a subset of the libraries. You still need to separately install CUDA to get the drivers and the full package